# Masking inputted text using canvas on android kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-canvas, android-paint

I'm currently doing a custom pin code and doing it with a canvas and paint, Unfortunately I cant seems to copy what the iputType="numberPassword" is doing with my custom design, I want to show the number momentarily before masking it and proceed to the next pin.

Here is my customEditText

```
class CustomEditTextPinViewMask : AppCompatEditText {
constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
    init(context, attrs!!)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
) {
    init(context, attrs!!)
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
constructor(
    context: Context?,
    attrs: AttributeSet?,
    defStyleAttr: Int,
    defStyleRes: Int
) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

val XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

private var mSpace = 24f//24 dp by default, space between the lines
private var mCharSize = 0f
private var mNumChars = 6f
private var mLineSpacing = 8f //8dp by default, height of the text from our lines
private var mMaxLength = 6
private var mClickListener: View.OnClickListener? = null
private var mLineStroke = 1f//1dp by default
private var mLineStrokeSelected = 2f//2dp by default
private var mLinesPaint: Paint? = null
private var mLinesGone: Paint? = null
private var mPaint: Paint? = null
val mStates = arrayOf(
    intArrayOf(R.attr.state_selected),
    intArrayOf(R.attr.state_focused),
    intArrayOf(-R.attr.state_focused)
)

val mColors = intArrayOf(
    -0x493800,//Green color = 0xFFB6C800
    -0x333334,//Gray color = 0xFFCCCCCC
    -0x333334
)

val mColorStates = ColorStateList(mStates, mColors)

private fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) {
    val multi = context.resources.displayMetrics.density
    mLineStroke *= multi
    mLineStrokeSelected *= multi
    mLinesPaint = Paint(paint)
    mLinesPaint!!.strokeWidth = mLineStroke
    mLinesPaint!!.color = Color.parseColor("#969696")
    mLinesGone = Paint(paint)
    mLinesGone!!.strokeWidth = mLineStroke
    mLinesGone!!.color = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")
    mPaint = Paint(paint)
    setBackgroundResource(0)
    mSpace *= multi //convert to pixels for our density
    mLineSpacing *= multi //convert to pixels for our density
    mMaxLength = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID, "maxLength", 6)
    mNumChars = mMaxLength.toFloat()

    //Disable copy paste
    super.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(object : ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode) {}
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    })
    // When tapped, move cursor to end of text.
    super.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v ->
        setSelection(text!!.length)
        if (mClickListener != null) {
            mClickListener!!.onClick(v)
        }
    })
}

override fun setOnClickListener(l: View.OnClickListener?) {
    mClickListener = l
}

override fun setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(actionModeCallback: ActionMode.Callback?) {
    throw RuntimeException("setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback() not supported.")
}

private fun getColorForState(vararg states: Int): Int {
    return mColorStates.getColorForState(states, Color.GRAY)
}

private fun updateColorForLines(next: Boolean) {
    if (isFocused) {
        mLinesPaint!!.strokeWidth = mLineStrokeSelected
        mLinesPaint!!.color = getColorForState(R.attr.state_focused)
        mLinesPaint!!.color = getColorForState(R.attr.state_window_focused)
        if (next) {
            mLinesPaint!!.color = getColorForState(R.attr.state_selected)
        }
    } else {
        mLinesPaint!!.strokeWidth = mLineStroke
        mLinesPaint!!.color = getColorForState(-R.attr.state_focused)
    }
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
   // super.onDraw(canvas)
    val availableWidth = width - paddingRight - paddingLeft
    if (mSpace < 0) {
        mCharSize = availableWidth / (mNumChars * 2 - 1)
    } else {
        mCharSize = (availableWidth - mSpace * (mNumChars - 1)) / mNumChars
    }
    var startX = paddingLeft
    val bottom = height - paddingBottom

    //Text Width
    val text: Editable? = text
    val textLength = text?.length
    val textWidths = FloatArray(textLength!!)
    paint.getTextWidths(getText(), 0, textLength, textWidths)

    //If Wanted to change text Color
    var i = 0
    while (i < mNumChars) {
        updateColorForLines(i == textLength)
        canvas.drawLine(
            startX.toFloat(), bottom.toFloat(), (startX + mCharSize) + letterSpacing,
            bottom.toFloat(), mLinesPaint!!
        )

        if (getText()!!.length > i) {
            val middle = startX + mCharSize / 2

            canvas.drawText(text, i, i + 1, middle - textWidths[0] / 2,
                bottom - mLineSpacing, paint)

            mLinesGone!!.strokeWidth = mLineStrokeSelected

            canvas.drawLine(
                startX.toFloat(), bottom.toFloat(),
                startX + mCharSize, bottom.toFloat(), mLinesGone!!
            )
            canvas.drawLine(
                startX.toFloat(), bottom.toFloat(),
                startX + mCharSize, bottom.toFloat(), mLinesGone!!
            )
            canvas.drawLine(
                startX.toFloat(), bottom.toFloat(),
                startX + mCharSize, bottom.toFloat(), mLinesGone!!
            )
        }
        if (mSpace < 0) {
            var mCharSizeMult = mCharSize * 2
            startX = (startX + mCharSizeMult).toInt()
        } else {
            var mCharSizeMspace = mCharSize + mSpace.toInt()
            startX = (startX + mCharSizeMspace).toInt()
        }
        i++
    }
}
```

}

This is how i implement it on my xml

```
 <com.sample.ui.widget.CustomEditTextPinViewMask
        android:id="@+id/pv_pincode"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:letterSpacing="1"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:textColor="@color/text_label_black"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="28sp"/>
```

This is how it will look like when shown on the phone [image]

How can i mask it? I'm also open for any sugestions thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **[setTransformationMethod()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod)** for masking it.

You can use this to mask the edittext .

```
//by default
edittext.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
//You can make it custom
edittext.setTransformationMethod(new AsterPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

here is the AsterPasswordTransformationMethod class

```
public class AsterPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
    };
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input, But I need to use my paint canvas and manually draw the text because of that specific UI, Which this method can't do.